# Need to force 100% height of child DIV with z-index

Tags: html, css, height

I am trying to force a child DIV to 100% height within a parent DIV.

The parent div contains an image at z-index:1

The child div is z-index: 9999

I can;t get the child DIV to force 100% height.

```
#protect_wrap   { width: 100%; 
                  float: left; 
                  background: #FFFFFF;
                  margin-top:0px;
                  text-align: center;
                  height: 100%;}

#protect_wrap img { z-index:1;}

#protect_col1    { width:200px;
                   margin: 0 auto; 
                   background: yellow;
                   z-index:999;
                   position:relative;
                   min-height: 100%;}

img.responsive-fill { width: 100%;
                      float: left; 
                      height: auto;}


<div id="protect_wrap">
     <img src="img/protect.jpg" class="responsive-fill">
     <div id="protect_col1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `#protect_col1` position to absolute and set it parent `#protect_wrap` to relative, the child will follow the parent height & width.

Comment: gorillaboxrc.com/res Look at the bottom of the page. –

Comment: Remove #protect_wrap height seems to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

`min-height` is different from `height`. You can only `min-height: 100%` if the parent has some value in `min-height`. Can you use `height` for the child div?

Answer (score 0):

Can you have this have these changes?

```
#protect_wrap   {
  position:relative;
  .......
}
#protect_col1    { 
  ..........
  position:absolute;
}
```